# Calculating Affine Transformation matrix from 4 corner points

Tags: image-processing, matlab, octave

I'm trying to develop a sudoku solver, using image processing, ocr with neural networks and such. I've got the bare solver working, I can successfully interpret numbers and letters from a picture. All of this is done in GNU Octave. Now I am trying to make it more robust, and I've found this question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square) which greatly helped with most of the image processing. But now I am left with the last part - transforming the single "squares" so that they are uniform and (mostly) square.
What I would like to have: A method that from one set of $(X,Y)$ corner coordinates, e.g.:$(73,86), (117,88), (70,127), (115,128)$ would transform the image with interpolation to the set of coordinates, e.g.: $(0,0), (50,0), (0,50), (50,50)$.

I have looked at the functions supplied with octave and there are these possibilities:

- [imperspectivewarp](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imperspectivewarp.html)
- [imremap](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imremap.html)

but both of them require, for me to know the affine matrix.

Is there a thing I've overlapped with these functions, or could someone here point me in a direction to develop such a function?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the pairs of corresponding two points from each coordinate,
you can use the function [**fitgeotrans**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html)
 to calculate the transformation matrix.

Once you have got the transformation matrix, the transformation can be done with [**imwarp**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html?searchHighlight=imwarp).

Note that you are going to use **Homography transformation** rather than affine transformation in this case (because you have specified corresponding 4 points, which may cause trapezoidal distortion).

The code would be like this...

```
% assume that the input image is in the variable inputImage.
nPixelsX = 50; % assume that there is square image with 50 pixels for each axes after transformation.
nPixelsY = 50;

movingPoints = [73,86; ...
                117,88; ...
                70,127; ...
                115,128]; % set image's corresponding points
fixedPoint = [0,0; ...
              nPixelsY,0; ...
              0,nPixelsX; ...
              nPixelsY,nPixelsX]; % set ideal coordinate's corresponding points
transformationType = 'Projective';  % this should be homology transformation
tform = fitgeotrans(movingPoints,fixedPoints,transformationType); % make transformation matrix

resultReference = imref2d([nPixelsY, nPixelsX]);
desiredImage = imwarp(inputImage, tform, 'OutputView', resultReference); % transform
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this theoretically answers my question - but your answer is for Matlab(Don't know why, but a moderator added a matlab tag to my post). Octave has not yet implemented the fitgeotrans function.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, but I haven't done it yet in Octave... Let's look forward to coming expert person in Octave.